# SharedPreferences value needs to be reset every other time

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

So,in this included flutter code,I am using a if loop in `checkFirstSeen()` to set my `seen` boolean to a value. This will then set my `SharedPreferences` value for the app. However,on every other restart of the application,I have to press the GotoHomepage button as opposed to it working automatically based off of the `SharedPreferences` value that was set. How can I fix this?

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:audiotest/UI/homepage.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
        title: "TestAudio",
        initialRoute: '/intro_route',
        routes: {
          '/intro_route': (context) => IntroScreen(),
          '/homescreen_route': (context) => MainPersistentTabBar2(),
        }));

class IntroScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  IntroScreenstate2 createState() => IntroScreenstate2();
}

class IntroScreenstate2 extends State<IntroScreen> {
  bool buttonstatus = true;
  Future checkFirstSeen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool seen = (prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);
    prefs.setBool('seen', false);
    if (buttonstatus == false) {

      prefs.setBool('seen', true); 
    }



    if (seen == true) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/homescreen_route');

    } else {

    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {

      checkFirstSeen();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('This is the placeholder for the TOS'),
            new MaterialButton(
              child: new Text('Go to Home Page'),
              onPressed: () {
                buttonstatus = false;
                checkFirstSeen();
                //Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/homescreen_route');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can get `seen` in `main()` and check `seen` directly in `initialRoute`

code snippet

```
bool seen;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  seen = await prefs.getBool("seen");
  await prefs.setBool("seen", true);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ...
      initialRoute:
          seen == false || seen == null ? "/intro_route" : "/homescreen_route",
      routes: {
        '/homescreen_route': (context) => MainPersistentTabBar2(
              title: "demo",
            ),
        "/intro_route": (context) => IntroScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]
[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

bool seen;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  seen = await prefs.getBool("seen");
  await prefs.setBool("seen", true);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute:
          seen == false || seen == null ? "/intro_route" : "/homescreen_route",
      routes: {
        '/homescreen_route': (context) => MainPersistentTabBar2(),
        "/intro_route": (context) => IntroScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MainPersistentTabBar2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MainPersistentTabBarState2 createState() => MainPersistentTabBarState2();
}

class MainPersistentTabBarState2 extends State<MainPersistentTabBar2> {
  Brightness brightness;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 90,
                  height: 40,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Session 1"),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 90,
                  height: 40,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Session 2"),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 90,
                  height: 40,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Session 3"),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 90,
                  height: 40,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Session 4"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Own The Tone '),
            /*actions: <Widget>[
              PopupMenuButton<String>(
                onSelected: _choiceAction,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Constants.choices.map((String choice) {
                    return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                      value: choice,
                      child: Text(choice),
                    );
                  }).toList();
                },
              )
            ],*/
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              FirstScreen(),
              Center(child: Text("Sample two")),
              Center(child: Text("Sample three")),
              Center(child: Text("Sample four")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // This area controls the settings menus
  /* void _choiceAction(String choice) {
    if (choice == Constants.about) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('About the app'),
          ),
          body: new PageView(),
        );
      }));
    } else if (choice == Constants.settings) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return new Scaffold(

          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Settings'),
          ),
          body: new Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('placeholder'),
              )),
        );
      }));
    }
  }*/
}

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstScreenState createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("First Screen"),
        ),
        body: Text("First"));
  }
}

class IntroScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IntroScreenState createState() => _IntroScreenState();
}

class _IntroScreenState extends State<IntroScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Introduction"),
        ),
        body: Text("Intro"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have modified your code to fit my use case,the code is in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/Nucl3arSn3k/8bbbeb8b3dd9e76687936ce39af38819) However,when I launch the app,I get a blank white screen with nothing displayed,that I then have to tap to get to MainPersistentTabBar2.

Comment: I have checked your gist. it works fine. the error is in MainPersistentTabBar2 not related to this, you have to check error log again. or you can post your code of MainPersistentTabBar2

Comment: I've posted the code for tab bar at [this](https://gist.github.com/Nucl3arSn3k/589cfb08ea9c186eccf177f5f68e596f) gist.

Comment: works fine after add FirstScreen() and mark Constants. because gist do not have Constants. see update full code and animated gif